# How do I transfer my packages after installing a new Julia version?

Tags: package, julia

I recently updated my Julia installation (to v1.3), but my packages didn't transfer automatically. What's the easiest way to transfer/add them all to the new version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the environments folder in your .Julia folder and then copy and paste the `Project.toml` and `Manifest.toml` file into the 1.3 environment folder.

Note that if the 1.3 folder doesn’t show up initially, just add something random in the package manager to generate the Project and Manifest file.

Comment: To clarify, I think that this just tells the new 1.3 environment that these packages should be part of its environment. Because they were already added and in the `/.julia/packages/` directory, it's just point 1.3 to them? No need to run anything extra in the REPL?

Comment: Yes. Some packages might need to be rebuilt for the new Julia version, but they will complain about that when you try to use them.

Comment: Also, don't forget to run `Pkg.update()` after copying the Project.toml and Manifest.toml files.